# What is the difference between collateral types ETH-A and ETH-B?

Tags: dai

Upon trying to create DAI for the first time via the Oasis app, I am first faced with a choice between two collateral types:

1. ETH-A
2. ETH-B

I see that they have different stability fees, liquidation rations and availabilities.

The two are also mentioned [here](https://github.com/makerdao/auction-keeper/blob/master/README.md#usage).

My question is: What are they and what's the difference between the two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are two different collateral types which allow for different DAI loans.
More specifically:

- ETH-A allows up to 590 million Dai to be generated with a Stability Fee of 2% and a Liquidation Ratio of 150%
- ETH-B allows up to 15 million Dai to be generated with a Stability Fee of 4% and a Liquidation Ratio of 130%

This guide is not 100% accurate since the stability fees vary.

source: https://blog.makerdao.com/a-guide-to-dai-stats/

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple Vault types for some collaterals. Each type indicated by a letter has its own Collateralization Ratio, and Stability Fee. You can pick whatever type of Vault you want according to your needs and risk profile.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).